# Is there a way to mirror another repo's master to a non-master branch only?

Tags: git, github, clone, mirroring

I have two repos - repo 1 and repo 2, and repo 1 has two branches - a master branch and branch 1. I want to be able to mirror repo 2's master branch to branch 1 only, and leave repo 1's master branch as is. Is there a way to do that? Is there also a way to mirror a specific branch to the master of another repo (i.e. mirror repo 1's branch 1 to repo 2)?

I've tried following your typical git clone --mirror URL , and then git push --mirror URL to repo 1. However, this seems to only push the mirror to the master branch of repo 1. I've also seen some people reference possibly doing a git push branch1 --mirror URL, but for this, I get a fatal: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs .

In some of the other questions similar to this, the solution hasn't necessarily been to mirror to and mirror from a specific branch. Unfortunately I'm facing this particular use case, and can't mirror to and from the master, but need to do it from a particular branch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do anything you want here.  The real trick is to figure out what you want, first.  After that, it's just a matter of *refspecs*, which I'll get to in a moment.  Given what you've said above, though, you *don't* want any of the `--mirror` options.

#### Fetch, push, names, and commit hashes

First, remember that Git is really all about *commits*.  Commits are uniquely identified by their hash IDs.  These hash IDs are universal: every Git everywhere agrees that some particular commit has *that one* hash ID.  No other Git anywhere can ever use that same hash ID for a different commit, and every Git everywhere must, if it has that commit, use *that* hash ID.

In other words, hash IDs have a real, concrete meaning.  It's the hash IDs that matter.  They are the currency of Git-to-Git exchange.

*Branch names*, by contrast, are specific to one Git repository or another.  Your `master` can be completely unrelated to *my* `master`, even if our two Git repositories are to exchange commits.  I have my Git call up your Git; your Git tells me that *your* `master` is commit `a123456...`; I get that commit from you, and it's still `a123456...`, but the name I have my Git use is something else entirely, such as `origin/master` or `dinh/master` or `yourbranch` or whatever *I* want to call it.  If you say `a123456...` and I say `a123456...` we can tell we both have *that* commit.  Your *name*, if any, and my *name*, need not agree, and with `git fetch`, they typically *don't* agree.

The `git push` command isn't quite symmetrical, but it works pretty similarly: I have my Git call up your Git, offer you some commit(s) by raw hash ID (and your Git and mine agree on those as usual).  Then I ask (regular push) or command (force-push) *your* Git to set one or more of *your* names to identify some specific commits, which I name by their universal, agreed-on hash IDs.

My Git can see your names when I run `git fetch` to your repository.  The default for `git fetch` is that I have my Git copy your names, *renaming* them: that's why you'll typically have an `origin/master` in your Git, after you have your Git copy things from another Git you're calling `origin`.  Meanwhile, I have my Git tell your Git some name to use when I run `git push` *from* my repository.  For convenience, I'll usually tell your Git *my* branch name when I `git push`.  That's why you typically push your `master` to origin's `master`: there's no default renaming happening here.

#### Hash IDs vs references

If hash IDs are how Git finds commits—and they are—then why, exactly, do we have branch names at all?  Well, consider some actual hash IDs in an actual Git repository:

```
83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6
aa8c8d914e4ae709e4fd025f359594f62653d9e5
061ed420ec2dc97e2a922a6f02992869089cefb3
```

These are three commits, in the order they were made (newest first).  Can you remember any of these numbers?  (Maybe—but I wouldn't *want* to.)  Git *needs* to remember *all* of them, but Git is set up so that commit `83232e...` itself remembers the number `aa8c8d...`, and `aa8c8d...` remembers the number `061ed4...`.  So we only need to remember that big ugly `83232e...` one.  We could write it down; but it might be nicer if we had Git write it down *for* us.

We can do this with a branch name, a tag name, or any other such name.  The *name* will hold `83232e...` and now we only need to remember the *name*.  These names are, collectively, what Git calls *refs* or *references*.  Branch names are names that start with `refs/heads/`, tag names start with `refs/tags/`, and remote-tracking names start with `refs/remotes/` and continue with the name of the remote (e.g., `refs/remotes/origin/`).  After the last slash, you have the branch, tag, or remote-tracking name itself.  Git tends to hide the prefix, but it shows up now and then, especially when using full references.

So, we have references—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on—that remember *one* hash ID.  From that one hash ID, Git finds the remaining hash IDs.  The only thing special about *branch* names is that we can use `git checkout` to get "on" the branch—`git status` will say `on branch master`—and then, once we do that, we can make a *new* commit.  The new commit we make will remember `83232e...` for us, and Git will automatically stuff the new commit's hash ID—which will be new and unique, different from every other commit ever—into `master`, which now automatically remembers the latest commit.

Hence, branch names just automatically designate the *last* commit in the branch.  From that commit, which Git finds by its hash ID—as found under the name—Git finds the *previous* hash ID, which gets Git to the commit, which gets another previous hash ID, and so on.  The result is the history: the series of commits that end at the designated tip, whose hash ID is stored in the branch name.

When `git fetch` and `git push` exchange commits, they do so by hash ID, but they also see, and sometimes copy, the names.  This is where *refspecs* come in.

#### Refspecs

A refspec is essentially a pair of references separated by a colon `:` character, e.g.:

```
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

You can put any reference on either side.  Here we have `master` on the left—`refs/heads/` marking it as a branch name—and `origin/master` on the right as a remote-tracking name.  The name on the left is the *source* and the name on the right is the *destination*.  This is the kind of refspec that `git fetch` uses, because the source reference is a branch name and the destination one is a remote-tracking name.  This tells your Git:  *Using their `master` branch, get any commits they have that I don't, and remember the one their `master` denotes, using my `origin/master`.*

With `git push`, you might write `git push origin master:master`.  Your Git will translate this to `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`—expanding the full name in place—and thus take any commits you have that they don't, send them over, and then ask them to set *their* `master` branch to the last commit in that chain.  Or you could `git push origin master:bren`, telling your Git to take your `master`—the source on the left side—and send any commits you have that they don't, but then ask them to set their branch `bren`.

You can—and in scripts at least, probably should—spell out the full names, complete with `refs/heads/` at the front.  This makes sure that if for some reason someone accidentally creates a *tag* named `master`, there's no ambiguity: you mean the *branch* `refs/heads/master`, not the *tag* `refs/tags/master`.

Any refspec can be preceded with a single plus-sign `+` character.  Doing so tells Git: *Do this operation even if you would normally object to it.*  That is, it sets the `--force` flag for this one particular reference update.  Git would normally object if changing a branch name would *lose* some commits, for instance.  That is, if the branch name currently says "commit a123456" which says "from here, go back one step to fedcba9", and you ask them to set their name to "fedcba9", they won't be able to find "a123456" any more—the directional links in commits point only *backwards*, to older commits, never forwards to newer ones.  (For more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

#### Refspec matching and the `--mirror` options

You can, and `git fetch` normally does, use the special `*` metacharacter to match *all* branches:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This fetch-oriented refspec says: *Take all of their branch names—everything under `refs/heads/`—and get all the commits and such and then forcibly update all of my remote-tracking names in `refs/remotes/origin/` to match.*  That's the normal refspec that `git fetch` uses to talk to a remote named `origin`.  That way, you get *all* their branches, as your remote-tracking names.

You can, however, use `git clone --mirror` to *change* this refspec to:

```
+refs/*:refs/*
```

This one says *Take all their references, regardless of what kind of names they are, and overwrite all **my** references with whatever hash IDs are in each of theirs.*  This means every `git fetch` replaces *all* your branch and tag names.  Any commits you have that they don't, you have now lost.  Any commits they have that you didn't, you now have—and your clone is now a mirror of theirs.

The `git push --mirror` command means that you'll have your Git command theirs (as with `--force` or a plus sign prefix) to:

- create any names you have that they don't;
- update any names that you have changed; and
- delete any names they have that you don't.

This completely wipes out all of their branch, tag, and other names, replacing them with yours.  (Of course, you'll first send any of your commits and other objects they'll need to complete this action.)  That does depend on them obeying the forceful operations, but that is the usual default setup.

The main thing to remember here is that in Git documentation, the word *mirror* means *take everything from the other:* one Git repository is never authoritative for anything, and the other is always authoritative for everything.  That's clearly not what you want!  You only want one repository to be authoritative for one branch.

You can do this in either direction: you can `git fetch repoA +refs/heads/theirs:refs/heads/mine` to replace your branch `mine` with whatever's the latest on `theirs`, and you can `git push repoB +refs/heads/mine:refs/heads/theirs` to replace *their* branch `theirs` with whatever's the latest on `mine`.  Except for where you run the command, and the direction of the data flow, these are almost symmetric: the only real difference is that with `git push`, they *can* refuse (through a pre-receive, update, or post-receive hook).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

You asked two questions:

- Mirror `repo1:branch1` to `repo2:master`
- Mirror `repo2:master` to `repo1:branch1`

You can do both of these with basically the same procedure.

---

**Mirror `repo1:branch1` to `repo2:master`**

1. Clone `repo1`.

   ```
   git clone <git URL for repo1>
   ```
2. Enter your new clone.

   ```
   cd repo1
   ```
3. Set up a new remote for `repo2`'s `master` branch.

   ```
   git remote add -t master repo2 <git URL for repo2>
   ```
4. Checkout `repo1:branch1`

   ```
   git checkout branch1
   ```
5. Push `repo1:branch1` to `repo2:master`.

   ```
   git push repo2 +branch1:master
   ```

---

**Mirror `repo2:master` to `repo1:branch1`**

1. Clone `repo2`.

   ```
   git clone <git URL for repo2>
   ```
2. Enter your new clone.

   ```
   cd repo2
   ```
3. Set up a new remote for `repo1`.

   ```
   git remote add -t branch1 <git URL for repo1>
   ```
4. Checkout `master` for `repo2` (may already be checked out)

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
5. Push `repo2:master` to `repo1:branch1`

   ```
   git push repo1 +master:branch1
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Very useful to have the steps listed out as concisely as you have - it made it very easy for me to follow.

Comment: In Step 3, branch1 should be repo1.

Comment: In step 3, branch1 is as it should be, but repo1 should follow it before repo1's URL.

Comment: Additionally, if there are authors on repo2 that are not on repo1, you may run into issues that can be solved in a variety of ways.  For gitlab, the simplest method to resolve author issues is to turn off "Check whether the commit author is a GitLab user" in repo1's repository "push rule" settings.